# Using variables or associative arrays in Perl regular expression operator for file input

Tags: regex, perl

I am writing a perl script to filter only the records from /etc/passwd that matches my login name. But when I include a variable or hash table between the "/ /" to be matched by the pattern matching operator, it works only for the standard input, if I pass /etc/passwd filename argument to my perl script then it returns empty results. How to solve this issue?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
while (<>) {
    my $x = `logname`;
    #if ($_ =~ /$x/) {
    if ($_ =~ /$ENV{'LOGNAME'}/) {
       print $_;
    }
}
```

./test.pl /etc/passwd ==> returns blank output

Comment: That should be fine unless your logname contains some symbols as well as letters and numbers

Comment: Thank you all for the inputs. The problem got solved by using chomp() function as ``chomp(my $x = `/usr/bin/whoami`);``  And the associative array was already working, and I failed to notice it.

Answer (score 3):

Borodin is right, your script works fine for me whether I do ...

```
cat /etc/passwd | ./test.pl
```

or...

```
/test.pl /etc/passwd
```

However, a few things.... If you're so inclined, your script could be shortened to this...

```
while (<>) {
    print if /$ENV{USER}/;
}
```

Perl golfers might shorten further, but this is about as short as I like while still making it's purpose obvious.

If (as Borodin suggested) you have some character in your username that is throwing the regex off... you can either escape your meta characters with `quotemeta( $ENV{USER} )` or, preferably, don't use a (comparatively costly) regex when you're just matching a sub-string... Instead, use the `index` function...

```
while (<>) {
    print if index( $_, $ENV{USER} ) != -1; 
}
```

The `index` builtin return the index at which a sub-string occurs (eg, `out` occurs in `bout` at index `1`, and occurs in `throughout` at index `7`) or it returns `-1` if the sub-string does not occur.

**EDIT**

I forgot to mention a little *gotcha* with the `index` function... it is case sensitive. If you want it to be case insensitive, the best way is to just force the case on your arguments to be the same, like this...

```
print if index( lc($_), lc($ENV{USER}) ) != -1;
```

In this example, I am forcing both arguments to `index` to be in lowercase.